# iOS 7 Music app crashes on startup

Tags: itunes, ipad, music, ios

I just upgraded to iOS 7 and my Music app is now crashing every time I try to launch it.

I've tried rebooting my iPad, disabling iTunes Match, re-enabling iTunes Match, but nothing seems to let me access my music.

Any thoughts on how I can reset my Music app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the tip from Meryovi, I was able to resolve this.  The instructions on the link he supplied were close but not the complete story.

I had to:

1. Perform a complete backup to iTunes on my computer (not iCloud)
2. Go to Settings -> iCloud -> Manage Storage ->  -> Delete Backup. (I don't know if this is strictly necessary or not)
3. Go to Settings -> General -> Reset and select "Erase All Content and Settings"
4. Do a full restore.

This solved my problem with the Music app crashing, the Settings app crashing on the About page, the iTunes app crashing, and the "could not be completed" failure during iCloud backups.

Answer (score 1):

This has been reported [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5326879) on Apple Support Community. Please try the solution posted there to see if it helps you.

Basically, their suggestion is to restore a backup of the device.